# What lenses could I get for EOS 60D beyond the kit? 

Tags: lens, canon-60d, canon-ef

I have just bought the EOS 60D and I am thinking to buy some new lenses.

What are the next best lenses to buy to get more detail in my pictures and do they have to be EF-S lenses (like the kit lens that I have)?

Comment: Hi shazmeen, welcome to the site. As it stands, your question is a bit vague and possibly a duplicate of other questions (see this for example: http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/7891/canon-starter-level-lenses ) Have you already gone through other questions on this topic and found that you still had some doubts? In that case, you should edit your question accordingly so that we can try to answer.

Comment: See also [What is the difference between EF and EF-S lenses?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/380/what-is-the-difference-between-ef-and-ef-s-lenses), [What should I buy as my first (and initially only) lens to go with a Canon 60D?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/18029/what-should-i-buy-as-my-first-and-initially-only-lens-to-go-with-a-canon-60d)

Answer (score 2):

You can use all EF and EF-S lenses. for the lens choice I suggest you to see [suggestions by cameralabs.com](http://www.cameralabs.com/lenses/lens_buyers_guide/Canon_EF_lenses/Recommended_Canon_lenses.shtml), but it all depends on your needs and your budget.

Answer (score 2):

What do you mean by "Bigger"? in camera land we talk about "length" (Focal length, in mm) and "speed" (how wide of an aperture it has then wide open, 2.8f, 1.4f etc etc)

Your question has no definite answer.

It depends entirely on budget, and subject.

Answer (score -1):

buy the 50mm 1.4 or the 85mm 1.8... they're both really good and worth the money

Comment: I'm interested. Can you expand a little bit? What makes these particular lenses especially good?

Comment: You have a crop-sensor camera...so a 50mm or a 85mm would be a good portrait lens... u can get some really nice results with these.. and they're fast... loads better for low-light than the kit lens. I've personally been using the 50mm 1.8 for quite a while now, and I like the results... though im looking for something at the wider end currently..